# Integrating $\sin^2\left({\pi}x\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{{\pi}nx}{2}\right)$ (problems with finding common denominator)

Tags: integration

[image]

I know it's not a very difficult one but I am struggling to find the final line.

I am actually finding the partial differential equations and I need to find the integral of $\sin^2\left({\pi}x\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{{\pi}nx}{2}\right)$. I understand and successfully compute the integral part to get the second line above. However, I feel difficult when trying to simplify the second line to the third line above.

My attempt:

The first term denominator: $2\pi n + 8\pi$

The second term denominator: $\pi n$

The third term denominator: $2\pi n - 8\pi$

My concern is that multiplying them directly will result in complicated calculation. I think there's some identity to solve the $\cos(\frac{\pi (n+4) x}{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$n(n-4)\cos \frac{\pi (n+4)x}{2}-2(n+4)(n-4)\cos \frac{\pi nx}{2} +n(n+4) \cos \frac{\pi (n-4)x}{2} $$

$$=n^2 \left(\cos \frac{\pi (n+4)x}{2}-2\cos \frac{\pi nx}{2}+\cos \frac{\pi (n-4)x}{2} \right)+4n \left(\cos \frac{\pi (n-4)x}{2} - \cos \frac{\pi (n+4)x}{2} \right)  +32\cos \frac{\pi nx}{2} $$

$$=n^2 \left(\cos \frac{\pi (n+4)x}{2}+\cos \frac{\pi (n-4)x}{2} -2\cos \frac{\pi nx}{2}\right)+4n \left(\cos \frac{\pi (n-4)x}{2} - \cos \frac{\pi (n+4)x}{2} \right)  +32\cos \frac{\pi nx}{2} $$

Applying compound formula
$$\cos A- \cos B=2\sin \frac{B-A}{2}\sin \frac{B+A}{2}$$

$$\cos A+ \cos B=2\cos \frac{A-B}{2}\cos \frac{B+A}{2}$$
$$\sin 2A= 2\sin A \cos A$$
and collecting like terms should yield the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to first deal with power $2$ in $\sin^2(\pi x)$ with double-angle formula followed by compound-angle formula.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \sin ^2(\pi x) \sin \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}\right) d x \
= & \int \frac{1-\cos (2 \pi x)}{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}\right) d x \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\left[\int \sin \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}\right) d x-\int \cos (2 \pi x) \sin \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}\right) d x\right] \\
= & -\frac{1}{\pi n} \cos \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \int\left[\sin \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}+2 \pi x\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}-2 \pi x\right)\right] d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{\pi n} \cos \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \int\left[\sin \frac{(n+4) \pi x}{2}-\sin \frac{(n-4) \pi x}{2}\right] d x \\
= & -\frac{1}{\pi n} \cos \left(\frac{\pi n x}{2}\right)+\frac{\cos \frac{(n+4) \pi x}{2}}{2(n+4) \pi}-\frac{\cos \frac{(n-4) \pi x}{2}}{2(n-4)\pi}+C
\end{aligned}
$$